# C#: Simple HTTP server

Tags: c#, http, httplistener

Based on MS example code I wrote a simple HTTP server.

```js
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8000/");

while (true)
            {
                listener.Start();
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

                // Obtain a response object.
                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                listener.Stop();
            }
```

It seems that at each loop must start with "listenet.Start" and end with "listener.Stop"
When I used only "listener.Start" before the loop, I stopped getting messages from a working Angular client after 2 messages.

Can you please tell why ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: listner.Start() is blocking call, i.e. execution stops there until a message is received. After message is received it runs through till the end of while loop. I am surprised that you get two messages when you move listner.Start() outside the while loop. It should be only one message since after first message you would run through the stop() statement, and then the while loop will just keep running without an active listner.